# Why some Gradle subproject tasks are accessible from root project?

Tags: java, gradle

I couldn't find any explanation on this topic, everywhere it's just given as a fact, but I'm interested in how that works.

For example let's take 'build' task, that's provided by 'java' plugin in subproject (but not available in root project).

- In root we can call *'gradle build'* or *'gradle :mysubproject:build'*
  eqally and subprojects build task will be called.
- However, in root project we cannot write *'build dependsOn
  someOtherTask'*, because it's not available in root - java plugin
  isn't added there.

**What makes build task available in root? Is there some property that makes task available in parent projects?**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `build` task is a [lifecycle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:lifecycle_tasks) (ie a task which doesn't actually do anything itself but it can `dependsOn` other tasks). See [base plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html#sec:base_plugins) which states the following about the `base` plugin

> Adds the standard lifecycle tasks

If you want the `build` task in the root project you'll need to add:

```
apply plugin: 'base'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call Gradle with task names as arguments in a multi-project build, each task with the specified name in any root or subproject will be executed. If you only want to execute a specific task of the given name, use task paths like `:mySubProject:build` for a subproject or `:build` for the root project.

Please note, that this has nothing to do with accessing a project in a `build.gradle` file. In this file, only the tasks of the current project are available. To access tasks in other projects, you could use their task container like `rootProject.tasks['build']` or `project(':sub').tasks['build']`. However, you may run into issues, cause the tasks might not be created when you try to access them.

For task dependencies, you can simply use strings that contain absolute task paths, like `dependsOn ':sub:build'` or `dependsOn ':build'`. Using just `'build'` will in this context only refer to the task with the specific name in the current project.

Comment: This seems to answer the original question and it seems to describe what happens.